# What is the best way to convert a synchronous method call to an asynchronous one?

Tags: java

I have several methods (involving network operations) which take quite a long time. I want to call them asynchronously and check the status from time to time. What's the recommended way to do it in Java?

Comment: Strong duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423210/recommend-a-better-way-to-turn-synchronous-methods-to-asynchronous-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [FutureTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html).
You give it the task, you can provide code to be run when the task is over (the protected `done` method), and you can check it's status with the `isDone` method. 
If you're writing a swing application you could also use [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using java 5 or above, you can use [`Executor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) otherwise you can use `threads`.

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous execution is done with Thread in Java. If you are new to that begin with [Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and [Runnable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and try to implement some code with them. When you got the idea switch to [java.util.concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Runnable.html) package.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Future interface and the associated documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html